# Determining User's role in a SharePoint site/workspace using the webservices API

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, permissions

How do I figure out the role(s) of a user in a site using the webservices API?  All I have to go on is the username and domain.

I've found that the PermissionsService.Permissions.GetPermissionCollection(url,"Web") will return a collection of permitted users and groups with their permissions masks but I still need to figure out if the user is in any of the groups and then convert the permissions masks into a roles collection.

I feel like there's a better way to do this and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Not necessarily. The SharePoint web services are pretty limited.

Answer (score 5):

I've solved something similar - my method checks if user is assigned a specific role. Here's the algorithm first:

1. Check if user is directly assigned a role at a site
2. If yes - cool, if not - get all the groups the user is a member of and get all the groups that have that role assigned to them.
3. Compare the two. If there is a matching - cool, if not - user is not assigned a role at that site level.

And the code:

```
public bool IsAssignedAPermission(string premissionName, string userLoginName)
    {
        XmlNode nodes;
        bool isAssignedAPermission;

        isAssignedAPermission = false;

        //Check if user is directly assigned a Full Control role
        try
        {
            nodes = userGroupService.GetRoleCollectionFromUser(userLoginName);
            using (XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(nodes))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(reader);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[1];
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string permission = row[1].ToString();
                    if (permission == premissionName)
                    {
                        isAssignedAPermission = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            List<string> groupMemberships;
            List<string> fullControlGroups;

            //Check if user is a member of a Full Control group
            //This is done in three steps:

            //1. Get the list of groups the user is member of
            groupMemberships = new List<string>();
            nodes = userGroupService.GetGroupCollectionFromUser(userLoginName);
            using (XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(nodes))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(reader);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[1];
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string groupName = row[1].ToString();
                    groupMemberships.Add(groupName);
                }
            }

            //2. Get the list of groups that have Full Control permissions
            fullControlGroups = new List<string>();
            nodes = userGroupService.GetGroupCollectionFromRole(premissionName);
            using (XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(nodes))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(reader);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[1];
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string groupName = row[1].ToString();
                    fullControlGroups.Add(groupName);
                }
            }

            //3. Check if user belongs to any of the Full Control groups
            foreach (string membership in groupMemberships)
            {
                if (fullControlGroups.Contains(membership))
                {
                    isAssignedAPermission = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return isAssignedAPermission;
    }
```

Method parameter userLoginName should be in a form domain\username, e.g. SHAREPOINT\Boris. I hope I helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In this blog post I use the UserGroup web service to list the SharePoint groups a user belongs to: http://www.theblackknightsings.com/ListAllSharePointGroupsAUserBelongsTo.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as users do not have to be part of SharePoint groups to have access to Sites or Site Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **GetRoleCollectionFromUser** method from the **UserGroup** web service, It'll give you the list of the roles to which the user belongs in your site.
Just call it passing as a parameter your domain\userName.
 
Find its definition here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772680.aspx

The returned xml will be something like the following, then you just get the info you need.

```
<GetRoleCollectionFromUser xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
<Roles>
<Role ID="1073741829" Name="Full Control" Description="Has full control." Order="1" Hidden="False" Type="Administrator" BasePermissions="FullMask" />
<Role ID="1073741825" Name="Limited Access" Description="Can view specific lists, document libraries, list items, folders, or documents when given permissions." Order="8" Hidden="True" Type="Guest" BasePermissions="ViewFormPages, Open, BrowseUserInfo, UseClientIntegration, UseRemoteAPIs" />
</Roles>
</GetRoleCollectionFromUser>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the user or group was explicitly added to the site, if you pass a username that is part of a group that has a defined it will throw an error.